# Reference callback with authentication in Orion Context broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I would like to protect the callback that I put in subscriptions. Is it possible?
I had a look in the documentation, but I was not able to find anything about it. The only workaround that I can think is to add a valid access token in the callback url and keep updating subscription on a time basis. Is there any better option?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you describe (to include the credentials as URI parameters in the subscription reference field) seems to be feasible.